# How can I expand lookup fields while using the /getitems end point?

Tags: 2013, javascript, rest, caml-query, sharepoint-on-prem

I have a query that filters a Workflow Tasks list to return only items where the task is assigned to either the current user or a group the current user is in:

```
<Or>
  <Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups">
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/>
  </Membership>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"></FieldRef>
    <Value Type="Integer">
      <UserID />
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Or>
```

I've been using this as the `caml` argument to the following method:

```
function getDataWithCaml(listName, caml) {
    var endpoint = "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"
        + listName + "')/GetItems";
    var requestData = { "query" :
        {"__metadata": 
            { "type": "SP.CamlQuery" }
            , "ViewXml": caml
        }
        };
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: endpoint,
        method: "POST",
        data: requestData,
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
        }
    });
}
```

This works fine and returns the filtered results, however what I can't figure out is how can I use this same filter but also expand the Editor and AssignedTo columns as is commonly done with the `/items` end point.

No matter how I specify the fields I get back `The $expand query is not valid for the field 'AssignedTo'`, even with something as simple as:

`/_api/Web/GetByTitle('Workflow Tasks')/getitems?$select=AssignedTo/Id&$expand=AssignedTo`

How can I expand the fields while maintaining the above filter?

Comment: is `AssignedTo` is a people field?

Comment: Yes; it's the column that comes with an out of the box Workflow Tasks list

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below REST API call? It worked for me.

```
siteurl/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Workflow Tasks')/Items?$select=AssignedTo/Id&$expand=AssignedTo
```

To get the current user tasks

```
var currentUserId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
var url = "siteurl/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Workflow Tasks')/Items?$filter=AssignedToId eq "+ currentUserId + "$select=AssignedTo/Id&$expand=AssignedTo"
```

Comment: That returns all the list items though; I only want items where the task is assigned to either the current user or a group the current user is in

Comment: check my answer above

Comment: That doesn't catch instances where the user is in a group and AssignedTo is set to that group.

Comment: It won`t work for the group. The out of the box list view filter has the same issue.

Comment: This is why I created this question. I have a filter that does what I want (see the first code section), it's a question of how to capture the expanded columns as well.

Comment: I am chasing the same question and it just occurred to me that instead of just hitting the REST endpoint with a POST and a CAML query, I need to just bite the bullet and make a JSOM call via the SP.ClientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle()... approach and request that the object model go ahead and expand everything out. I'm posting this as a comment b/c I don't have all the code handy (yet) to do that but if you've done any SP dev at all, you'll know what I'm talking about.